# Windows Phone 8 AppBar Command

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to get in my `AppBar` the style of command that you see in `about` below:

[image]

I can get buttons (like `add` and `settings`) to show up fine, but I can't find any way to show commands like `about`. Is this not supposed to be done in the `AppBar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Silverlight

Take a look at `Menu Items` in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff431813(v=vs.105).aspx)

Sample from documentation:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar Mode="Default" Opacity="1.0" IsMenuEnabled="True" IsVisible="True">

        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Click="Save_Click" IconUri="/Images/save.png" Text="save" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Click="Settings_Click" IconUri="/Images/settings.png" Text="settings" />

        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Click="MenuItem1_Click" Text="menu item 1" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Click="MenuItem2_Click" Text="menu item 2" />
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>

    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

#### WinRT

Use `CommandBar` where `PrimaryCommands` show up like `add/settings` and `SecondaryCommands` like menu item `about`. Take a look at this [article](http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/09/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-application-bar/) explaining the differences.

```
<page.BottomAppBar>
    <commandBar>
        <commandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <appBarButton Label="{Binding AppBarLabel}" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}">
                <appBarButton.Icon>
                    <pathIcon HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="Some path"/>
                </appBarButton.Icon>
            </appBarButton>
        </commandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <commandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <appBarButton x:Uid="AppBarSec" Label="$$get from resource$$" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}">
            </appBarButton>
        </commandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </commandBar>
</page.BottomAppBar>
```

Comment: I assume this is using a Silverlight project?